# how to run selenium script on google cloud using ubuntu instance

Tags: python

So, I have a project that is basically scraping twitter account's followers and now I have to run it on google cloud but the problem is I haven't done it before, so if anyone can guide me step by step it would be really appreciated. One more question is that can I update database records that is being uploaded on GCP with a python script running on my local machine 'windows'? If so, how?